# date not change when using setInterval in javascript

Tags: javascript

The date isn't changing when using `setInterval` in javascript.
Why doesn't the date change every second?

```
var myVar=setInterval(myTimer(),1000);
function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  document.write(d.toLocaleString());
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need to start the timer?

Comment: myTimer called 1 time and not called again why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="hh"></p>

<script>
  var myVar=setInterval(myTimer(),1000);
  function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("hh").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    //document.getElementById("hh").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this is not necessary `var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);`, see this code [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/76M5EGAe8phTWoOe21De?p=preview)

Answer (score 4):

You should not invoke the `myTimer` function in `setInterval`. You should pass the reference to `setInteval`

```
var myVar=setInterval(myTimer,1000);//corrected line
function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  document.write(d.toLocaleString());
}
```

Comment: same result it not called again and time is constant

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution is better, please check this example [Timer Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/76M5EGAe8phTWoOe21De?p=preview)

```
//When the document is loaded
document.addEventListener("load", myTimer);
//subsequent calls
setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
function myTimer(){
  var d = new Date();
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = d.toLocaleString();
}
```